# Thread stack in MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I am obtaining the following error in a MySQL instance:

```
[ERROR] Failed to write to mysql.slow_log: Thread stack overrun: 5375640560 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 81920 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

My questions are:
1) What does it mean by stack overrun?
2) Why am I getting a stack overrun?
3) If 81920 bytes are only needed, why is there a stack overrun of 5375640560 bytes??

Comment: I got the same error. Ever found a reason behind this?

Comment: Any material view creations involved in your DB via stored procedures??

Comment: Yup.. the issue has gone away. Had two fixes in place:
1) Moved away from x-large to 2x-;arge RDS instance (Pretty sure this isn't the reason why the error has gone away.
2) Replaced the material view creation (This should be your issue)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Nope, i have no materialized views created like that, but i do have a lot of materialized views regenerated on daily basis. I'm on db.r3.large.

Comment: Milovan, which database are you using? I had a similar issue; I replaced the material view refresh with minuscule momentary upserts and this led to pretty good improvements.. If I may ask, are you experiencing a lot of phantom spikes, as well?

Comment: I'm using Aurora MySql 5.6. The strange thing is that i"m seeing those ERROR messages throughout the day pretty much regardless of what activity the database is currently in. Performance on the other hand is really stable (no phantom spikes) and everything works really smooth. I'm just curious why are these errors happening. Perhaps it has to do something with data replication over AWS DMS?

Comment: Yes, maybe.. Also, The last time that I checked, there was no data-loss. Good for us!!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion :high-five:

Comment: @MilovanZogovic, Check out the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thread stack overrun is an inherent and a known issue in multiple versions of aurora (tested in 1.14). From the forums, it has been stated that the issue has been fixed in the new version of Aurora (Haven't tested this yet).

However, for the existing versions; this issue can be resolved by editing option **log-output** in the parameter groups as: **log-output: File**

Now, even the slow queries are visible, even in the logs option under monitoring.

Comment: Upgrading to aurora 1.16 solved this for me! Thanks for the help!